# Rendering an Image Using Threads Cause Noisy Pictures

Tags: java, multithreading, task, threadpool, runnable

I've built my own basic ray tracer.
I've tried to optimize its performance, so I thought of using threads.
When I render without threads - all looks good, but when I've tried to use threads - I've got a noisy picture with black stripes on it.

This is the code. for every line of pixels, I've created a new executor to calculate the pixel colors in that line:

```java
public void renderImage(){
        Camera camera = _scene.get_camera();

        for (int i = 0; i < _imageWriter.getWidth(); ++i){
            final int iFinal = i;

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executor.submit(() -> {
                for (int j = 0; j < _imageWriter.getHeight(); ++j){
                    ArrayList<Ray> rays = camera.constructRaysThroughPixel(
                            _imageWriter.getNx(), _imageWriter.getNy(),
                            iFinal, j, _scene.get_screenDistance(),
                            _imageWriter.getWidth(), _imageWriter.getHeight()
                    );

                    Color color = new Color();
                    for (Ray ray: rays) {

                        ArrayList<GeoPoint> intersectionPoints = _scene.get_geometries().findIntersections(ray);

                        if (intersectionPoints.isEmpty() == true) {
                            color = color.add(_scene.get_background());
                        }
                        else {
                            GeoPoint closestPoint = getClosestPoint(intersectionPoints);

                            color = color.add(new Color(calcColor(closestPoint, new Ray(camera.get_origin(), closestPoint.point.subtract(camera.get_origin())))));
                        }
                    }

                    int length = rays.size();
                    color = color.scale(1.0/length);

                    _imageWriter.writePixel(iFinal, j, color.getColor());

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is what I've gotten when I used threads:
[image]

This is what I've gotten when I didnt use threads:
[image]

Comment: Does this have to do with the order that your threads are executing in?

Comment: I dont think so because the pixels are printed to the BufferedImage in exact position each time, so no matter the order.

anyways, If i simply use a Runnable and then use run() on it - it works, but no difference in performence at all.

Comment: I think i know what the problem is.
I write the image even though not all the threads have finished their work.
How can I keep track of whether all threads are finished?

Comment: I would imagine adding a boolean value or some function to indicate "doneness" in the code that is executing would work. You can access these values in your main thread.